# How to save a file on any path of computer without dialog in c# uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, io, save, storage

I'm trying to save a file without a filepicker under my desktop or somewhere else, but I always get the error "Access to path [...] is denied"

This is my code:

```
    private async void SaveFile(string Path)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Path);
        StorageFile sampleFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }
```

I tried the same code but with the Localfoder and it worked.

Is there any way to get access to the path without a filepicker?

Comment: unrelated: `async void SaveFile` should be `async Task SaveFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FilePicker gets permission from the user to access file locations. File system access is a restricted capability in UWP. You can enable *Broad Filesystem Access* in your package manifest to get this permission when the app is installed. It's not recommended for apps published to the Microsoft Store, because it makes it less likely for you app to be approved. See the [App capability declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) documentation.

Alternatively, you could run your app from a folder that contains the desktop in one of its subfolders by using the AppExecutionAlias extension mention under *Accessing additional locations* in [File Access Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). Underneath that section there is also an explanation of *Broad Filesystem Access* as well.

Comment: My path is: @"C:\users\Julius\Desktop"

Comment: Did some more research on c# in UWP specifically and updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, that means there is no easy other way as getting acces to the folder from a filepicker... Thanks for your answer!